# Dynamic load all classes from hbm file

Tags: hibernate

How to load all classes that occurred in *.hbm.xml file with a customized classloader?

How to locate all the places the classes occurred?

Comment: What framework are you using except Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Hibernate 3.6 (I don't know if it changed for Hibernate 4.x):

What you can do: You extend the class `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` with your own subclass. In this class you override the methods `doConfigure()` and `buildSessionFactory()` for injecting your own customized classloader:

```
@Override
protected Configuration doConfigure(org.dom4j.Document doc) throws HibernateException {
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader stdLoader = me.getContextClassLoader();
    me.setContextClassLoader(new MyOwnClassloader(...));
    super.doConfigure(doc);
    me.setContextClassLoader(stdLoader);

    return this;
}
```

The same you have to do with `buildSessionFactory()`.

If you like you also can override `addResource()`. This allows you to accept a special syntax for your classloader where to find the mapping file or annotated class. (I did this when I made an OSGi integration. In the mapping filename I allowed a specification of the OSGi bundle where to find the mapping file.)

In your code you have to replace calls to the hibernate `Configuration` class with the calls to your class.

The bad thing is the poor object orientated design of the Hibernate `Configuration` class. Many methods return `this`, i. e. the instance which they are called for, but after creating your subclass these methods return a `this` of the wrong Java type. You have to override all these methods, just call the `super.xxx()` and return `this` in the type of your subclass.